# GFCI won’t turn on

Tags: gfci, pump, irrigation

I’m replacing the 1pole breaker at the main panel with a GFCI. This feeds a boat house (underground) that has sub panel with two breakers, one for an irrigation pump the other for lights and a switched 115v outlet. (Outlet is hot when the lights are on.) I want the GFCI for better protection because of the pump and we’re plugging in a single phase thruster motor used submersed in the lake.
I’m not understanding why the breaker immediately trips when neither load is on.
Is the GFCI that sensitive to where those connected sub-circuits look like a fault?
Or is the breaker bad? It was tough to get these days. (SqD QO). Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had the same problem with a CO detector that went off immediately... could never figure out what it was...  Pixies? Gremlins?  Electric fields? Some sort of, *I don't know*, invisible gas? :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

There is always the possibility that your new GFCI breaker is bad. But far more likely is that you have a fault - either improper wiring or an actual real ground fault.

Based on your description, it sounds like as soon as you turn on the breaker, the GFCI trips. Is that correct? If not, please clarify. But if that is the case, you need to narrow down the source of the trip in order to solve the problem.

- The GFCI breaker itself

Disconnect the hot and neutral going into the GFCI breaker. Reset it. Does it trip? If yes, you have a bad breaker. If no, move on.

- The feed to the Subpanel

Remove the two breakers from the subpanel. Turn on the GFCI breaker. Does it trip? If yes, you have either a fault in the wiring between the GFCI breaker and the subpanel (unlikely if it is a single section of wire/cable, but if there are any connections in junction boxes along the way where moisture could get in then that is a possibility) or the subpanel itself. If no, move on.

- The Subpanel breakers

Reinstall the two breakers into the Subpanel, but do *not* connect any loads to the breakers. Turn on the GFCI breaker. Does it trip? If yes, one of the breakers is causing a problem - test with one breaker (and then the other) to narrow it down and replace the problem breaker. If no, move on.

- Wires to the Loads

Reconnect the hot and neutral wires to the breakers (actually, at this level test one breaker/load at a time). Disconnect the wires from the actual loads (pump, receptacle, etc.) Turn on the GFCI breaker. Does it trip? If yes, you have a problem in the wires or junctions in those wires between the breaker and the load. If no, move on.

- Loads

Reconnect the loads (pump, receptacle, etc. one at a time). Turn on the GFCI breaker. Does it trip? If yes, you have a problem in that load. If no, keep trying the other loads until you find the problem.

The end result will most likely be finding an actual ground fault! Meaning finding a potentially life-threatening danger *and fixing it*. That might mean replacing a pump or receptacle. But that would mean you were living on borrowed time - be very glad you got the GFCI installed before the problem killed someone.

As noted by Harper, a neutral problem can cause GFCI trips as well. In particular, if you have neutral piggybacking on ground or vice versa at some point in the circuit (watch for any place that has a bare or green wire connecting to a white wire - that's an obvious case, though there can be more hidden ones as well) then that will lead to GFCI problems.

There is actually a non-zero possibility that at the end of this process you will *not* have found the problem and the problem will magically be fixed. That is possible if the problem was a loose connection that allowed water to get in and create a ground fault that got fixed by disconnecting and reconnecting everything. If that's the case, the problem might come back later - and trip the GFCI.

Comment: One of the most thorough troubleshooting guides I've seen on this site. +100 (if I could)!

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed troubleshooting direction. I will need to look again closer at the panel then start the process. I’ve already enlisted the home boss to be the breaker switcher so I’m not climbing back up the steep hill for every change. It should be fun.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit is leaking current causing it to trip. Be sure it is correctly wired. Sometimes over looked is if the neutral wire is grounded it will cause the breaker to trip. You can start by disconnecting each device starting with disconnecting the feed lines at the boat house, if it trips you have a bad underground cable or miss wired. If it holds try each load one at a time until you find the offending unit. It is possible it could be more than one. I have seen where two units were leaking just a bit and it would only trip when both were plugged in. Let us know how you make out. I am surprised you did not have a CFGI originally, I believe that is required by code when that close to water, depending on your area.

Comment: "required by code" depends on _when_ it was installed...

Comment: Thank you for the great input, and as I said above it should be interesting to see how this shakes out given the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the nugget of info you might be missing: **NEUTRAL-Ground faults will also trip a GFCI**.

We're used to taking neutral for granted and thinking only in terms of the hot wire.  Switch the hot, put the breaker on the hot, etc.  But the fact is, to a GFCI, a neutral-ground fault is the same as a hot-ground fault.  And there is no way to "switch off" your loads on the neutral side, because as said, we just don't bother to build that.

So, you can't narrow down and isolate a GFCI trip merely by throwing switches. Anytime you are isolating parts of the circuit for testing, you must actually open up junction boxes and disconnect the neutral as well as the hot.

Once you know that, it's a straightforward "divide and conquer" - keep disconnecting parts of the circuit at points, until the problem location is narrowed down to only one possibility.  Expect a faulty appliance or a wiring error.

Comment: Thank you for the great input as the main panel has grounds and neutrals tied. This is a 40 plus year old panel and I need to look closer at it and start troubleshooting process (see above)

Comment: Also, I’m surprised there aren’t more non-receptacle GFCI questions and problems discussed on the web. I’ve heard that it is a very common issue especially with remote buildings, near water etc.

Comment: In the main panel the neutral is supposed to be bonded to the ground, but that is the only place, not in branch panels.

Comment: @JHammer what you're *supposed to have* in a main panel is a neat and pretty neutral bar with all your neutrals, and a neat and pretty ground bar with all your grounds, and a paisley-colored Neutral-Ground Equipotential Bond wire linking the two bars.  However, builders said "Good grief, what is the difference even?" ... *and, well, they're not wrong*.  As such, main panels are allowed to have an "equipotential bond" that looks like all neutrals and grounds spammed on the same bar.